# Why can't I decode this json data using codable?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decodable

I am trying to decode a json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
"id": "bitcoin",
"symbol": "btc",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1510040391",
"current_price": 6419.05058467597,
"market_cap": 110769065096.2,
"market_cap_rank": 1,
"total_volume": 7134416215.16392,
"high_24h": 6999.30273116437,
"low_24h": 6265.34668792378,
"price_change_24h": "-580.08447091048",
"price_change_percentage_24h": "-8.28794510040892",
"market_cap_change_24h": "-10080785067.733",
"market_cap_change_percentage_24h": "-8.34157845794463",
"circulating_supply": "17252725.0",
"ath": 19665.3949272416,
"ath_change_percentage": -67.3505163492418,
"ath_date": "2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z",
"roi": null,
"last_updated": "2018-09-06T16:03:23.307Z"
  },
  {
"id": "ethereum",
"symbol": "eth",
"name": "Ethereum",
"image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1510040267",
"current_price": 226.482375502941,
"market_cap": 23071362046.6026,
"market_cap_rank": 2,
"total_volume": 3957109077.73956,
"high_24h": 256.816443923474,
"low_24h": 215.415109745597,
"price_change_24h": "-30.246516631482",
"price_change_percentage_24h": "-11.7815008587522",
"market_cap_change_24h": "-3068068475.6338",
"market_cap_change_percentage_24h": "-11.7373194990757",
"circulating_supply": "101792652.9678",
"ath": 1448.1800861342,
"ath_change_percentage": -84.320027361102,
"ath_date": "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
"roi": {
  "times": 46.14410145864465,
  "currency": "btc",
  "percentage": 4614.410145864465
},
"last_updated": "2018-09-06T16:03:23.331Z"
  },
```

I need this data to be accessible so that it is easy to access the prices, image url etc of bitcoin,ethereum or any in the list when needed.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    struct Coins: Decodable {

    let id: String
    let name: String
    let current_price: Double
} // I have also tried: let id: [String] etc.

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
    label.text = "Hello World!"
    label.textColor = .black

    view.addSubview(label)
    self.view = view

    let urlJSON = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=btc"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlJSON) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        //print(dataAsString)

        do {
            let coins = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coins.self, from: data)
            print(coins.id)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("error serializing json")
            print()
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

But I just get the "Error serializing json", although if I print the json as String, I get the full json so the urlsession works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `print("error serializing json");  print()` That's not useful. Instead do `print("error serializing json: \(jsonError)")` That should give you really interesting information about what went wrong. Like the fact that your JSON is an Array at top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doiing wrong.. please do like this

```
 let coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coins].self, from: data)
```

As you are getting array so you need to parse array of struct

```
struct Coins: Decodable {

        let id: String?
        let name: String?
        let current_price: Double?
    }
```

Comment: Do I also need to change the struct? This appeared to work once but I can't get that result again for some reason I still get the error. the json err also returns nil but the response works.

Comment: Yes, you need to add optional at the end because may be in the response values will be nill so please check my updated answer

Comment: @PeterRuppert: PLease show me your jsonErr , print(jsonErr)

Comment: Okay it is because I added a new let to the struct: let current_price: Double, error serializing json: valueNotFound(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1918", intValue: 1918), CodingKeys(stringValue: "current_price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Double value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Ok, add optional like my updated answer then it will work

Comment: Thank you that works. Do you know if I can access a certain row by the name: or can I only access them through coins[0] etc.

Comment: You can access with the index from the array

Comment: You don't need to make all properties of the struct optional. Only make a property optional if that particular value could be missing from the JSON.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary Done, Thanks. Is it possible to access the struct from outside the class? (Using it as a data source for API)

Comment: Yes, move struct outside the controller. then you can access the struct anywhere in project

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary I've done it by declaring var coinData = [Coins](), and then after the Codable function and parsing, did coinData = coins. Is that a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an Array, so you should use

```
JSONDecoder().decode([Coins].self, from: data)
```

Comment: This gives me "Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '([CGPrices.Coins.Type], from: Data)'"

Comment: @rmaddy My bad, I was in a hurry. Thanks for correcting